Why is python running in 3.8.5 if I'm using a Python 3.10 SDK?
I am trying to use Azure ML Studio for a project and am attempting to replicate a google colab '.ipynb' to rerun the code in my own compute instance.
For this, I searched for someone that had a similar problem to my own here on stack overflow and followed the steps in the solution, which included going to the terminal and activating the 3.10 SDK environment.
The code is running on python 3.10 in the google colab, and I am attempting to run the same code in my workspace but having issues with library compatibility. Lo and behold, my python version is still at 3.8.5
When I try this in a cell, I get 3.10.11
import sys, platform
print(sys.version)
print(platform.python_version())

When I try this though, I get Python 3.8.5 :
!python --version


Recreated the steps from the aforementioned solution
I restarted the kernel from the drop-down.
I tried to open the jupyter notebook from 'Manage' > 'Compute' > 'Applications' > 'Jupyter notebook' 
And even tried creating a new notebook with the same conditions as in ML Studio.
Selected the appropriate kernel, checked version again, only to continue to get 3.8.5
I was expecting the python version to be at 3.10 so I can run the code with its compatible version. Even still, I don't know what I am doing wrong or why the kernel won't execute the code in the expected python version. What can I do to ensure that I can run my python code in the 3.10 version already available in the kernel? Thank you

Post your code as text in the question itself. Images can't be copied, googled or tested

I believe that the version that the notebook is using is in fact 3.10.
When you do !python --version you might be getting the python that is in ´/user/lib´ instead of the one in the conda env. To know the python version that is used in the notebook, which is the same as in the conda environment, you can do print(sys.version)

thank you for being the first person to answer :) i really appreciate your reply. that means there are some errors intrinsic to the code and ML studio environment which haven't made it replicable in the workspace probably, which is surprising bc colab is also in 3.10 but whatever we'll figure it out. once again thank you

@katherine you'd get answers sooner if you included your code in the question itself as text, not images. Images can't be copied, tested or googled. If !python --version was visible, people would point out immediately that you aren't looking at the notebook's environment

I repeat - had you typed the text, so people can actually see what you ask, you'd get an answer in 5 minutes. There's nothing wrong with ML studio or the environment.

@PanagiotisKanavos thank you for editing the question. i'm new to stack overflow and have limited functionality with my account and also don't know how to optimize user interactions or get more people to help in answering a question.
